# Empty request logs

Tags: jetty

I've added this to `jetty.xml`:

```
<Get name="handler">
    <Call name="addHandler">
        <Arg>
            <New id="RequestLog" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler" />
        </Arg>
    </Call>
</Get>
<Ref id="RequestLog">
    <Set name="requestLog">
        <New id="RequestLogImpl" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.NCSARequestLog">
            <Arg>
                /home/aromanov/workspaces/odp-server/ru.focusmedia.odp.server.karaf.launcher/data/jettylog/yyyy_mm_dd.request.log
            </Arg>
            <Set name="retainDays">90</Set>
            <Set name="append">true</Set>
            <Set name="extended">true</Set>
            <Set name="logServer">true</Set>
            <Set name="logDispatch">true</Set>
            <Set name="LogTimeZone">GMT</Set>
        </New>
    </Set>
</Ref>
```

The log file is created, but after accessing the page in the browser (and getting "404, powered by Jetty"), nothing appears in the log. Why could this be?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your handler chain is not configured correctly.  Think of the request getting processed by a chain of handlers, and this logging handler is one that just makes a reference to the log file as the request processes through.  So if your not getting content in the log then your handler is not in the chain of execution that is occurring.  You likely just need to add it to the handler list, *before* something else that might handle it.