# How do I configure embedded jetty server to log all requests?

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

I want to log all soap requests to my server. The server instance is an embedded jetty server.

Is there a way to setup  a handler to do this. I have access to the web.xml file

Comment: If you want to do this non-programmatically (i.e. via `jetty.xml`) have a look at [the configuration in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861869/empty-request-logs). Worked for me in Jetty 8.1.13, where the embedded code was configuring `jetty.xml` *after* creating and injecting the `HandlerCollection` to the server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want the following on your embedded jetty startup...

### Jetty 12

You'll be using ...

1. The `CustomRequestLog` (which has syntax for it's output)
2. An instance of `RequestLog.Writer` to specify where that output will go.
3. Setting the `Server.setRequestLog(RequestLog)` with your configuration.

You will not use the old `RequestLogHandler` from Jetty 9 days,
as that class was incapable of logging any requests that did not dispatch through that handler. (eg: errors, bad requests, requests without paths, requests that don't match a configured context path, etc)

Both of the below examples are snippets from the jetty-example project at:

- https://github.com/jetty/jetty-examples/tree/12.0.x/embedded/requestlog

##### Example having a Writer that outputs to slf4j logging at an arbitrarily configured logger name

```java
Slf4jRequestLogWriter requestLoggingWriter = new Slf4jRequestLogWriter();
requestLoggingWriter.setLoggerName("examples.requests");

RequestLog requestLog = new CustomRequestLog(requestLoggingWriter,
    CustomRequestLog.EXTENDED_NCSA_FORMAT);

server.setRequestLog(requestLog);
```

You can use your logging library of choice (just have slf4j route to your logging library), and output those logging events anywhere your logging library supports (file w/overwrite, file w/append, file w/rollover, email, database, unix system logs, etc)

##### Example having a Writer that outputs to file.

```java
AsyncRequestLogWriter requestLogWriter = new AsyncRequestLogWriter();
requestLogWriter.setAppend(true);
requestLogWriter.setFilename("/var/web/logs/request.log");
requestLogWriter.setRetainDays(1);

RequestLog requestLog = new CustomRequestLog(requestLogWriter,
    CustomRequestLog.EXTENDED_NCSA_FORMAT);

server.setRequestLog(requestLog);
```

### Original Answer (Oct 18, 2013)

This is for Jetty 9

```java
    HandlerCollection handlers = new HandlerCollection();
    ContextHandlerCollection contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();
    // your context specific handlers are added to "contexts" here
    server.setHandler(handlers);

    NCSARequestLog requestLog = new NCSARequestLog();
    requestLog.setFilename("/path/to/my/logs/yyyy_mm_dd.request.log");
    requestLog.setFilenameDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd");
    requestLog.setRetainDays(90);
    requestLog.setAppend(true);
    requestLog.setExtended(true);
    requestLog.setLogCookies(false);
    requestLog.setLogTimeZone("GMT");
    RequestLogHandler requestLogHandler = new RequestLogHandler();
    requestLogHandler.setRequestLog(requestLog);
    handlers.addHandler(requestLogHandler);
```

Comment: Where so I add this. I am sorry I am very new to Jetty. Can I just configure this in web.xml

Comment: You said you had embedded jetty, that means you have some java code that starts your jetty server.  Look for that code, search for "new Server(".  Either that, or you are not using embedded jetty.

Comment: I do not have access to that part of code. All I have is a way to send parameters to jvm or edit web.xml. Is there a way to do it with web.xml

Comment: Not really.  the web.xml is for configuring the deployment of the webapp itself.  Access/Request logging is a function of the server.  However, you can fake it with a custom Filter of your own to log each request, but that would be custom code in your webapp, subject to the standard restrictions of the code of a webapp.

Comment: I suspect you are not using embedded jetty, but rather standalone jetty.  If that's the case, you should ask your administrators to enable `etc/jetty-requestlog.xml`

Comment: what does this do - "requestLog.setExtended" when set to true?

Comment: when you initialize and add handlers to contexts (ContextHandlerCollection contexts), it's not used anywhere in below. where do I need to hook it up with server it self with ContextHanderCollection?

Comment: I had to add `server.setRequestLog(requestLog);`

Comment: @MichałNiklas the `Server.setRequestLog()` [was added for Jetty 9.3+](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/commit/e3bda4efbefa2370d7d9b594aa97dc60a2b37235)

Comment: After following thes instructions, I can see debug logs in my console, which is great. But I'm unable to see the logs being outputted to any files.

Answer (score 2):

jetty maven:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-all</artifactId>
        <version>9.3.8.v20160314</version>
        <type>pom</type> 
   </dependency>
```

---

Code:

```
NCSARequestLog requestLog = new NCSARequestLog();
requestLog.setFilename("/path/to/my/logs/yyyy_mm_dd.request.log");
requestLog.setFilenameDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd");
requestLog.setRetainDays(90);
requestLog.setAppend(true);
requestLog.setExtended(true);
requestLog.setLogCookies(false);
requestLog.setLogTimeZone("GMT"); // or GMT+2 and so on. 

server.setRequestLog(requestLog); // here will set global request log
```

NCSARequestLog is sync log, if you want to use log4j, do it like that:

```
public class AccessLogHandler extends AbstractNCSARequestLog {
    private Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(AccessLogHandler.class);
    @Override
    protected boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(String requestEntry) throws IOException {
        logger.info(requestEntry);
    }

}
```

use `AccessLogHandler` to replace the `NCSARequestLog` and config your `log4j.properties`.