# How do I configure embedded Jetty server to print NCSARequestLog to STDOUT

Tags: java, heroku, jetty, embedded-jetty

I have an embedded Jetty server running on Heroku, and I want it to print request logs to STDOUT so I can capture device, IP, etc data.

I can see how to [configure NCSARequestLog to log to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19458875/how-do-i-configure-embedded-jetty-server-to-log-all-requests), but I can't find any way to redirect that to STDOUT.

How can I log request information from an embedded Jetty server to STDOUT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `NCSARequestLog` does not output to console, and cannot be configured to do that.

However, all is not lost, use the [`Slf4jRequestLog`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Slf4jRequestLog.html) instead and setup your slf4j log implementation to output those events to your console.